# What is fiber space？Is it related to the fiber bundle？

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, fiber-bundles

Recently I have heard about the so-called fiber space？And it is said that it is a kind of generalization of fiber bundle.So what is fiber space？How dose it relate to the fiber bundle？Thanks！

Comment: Please include perhaps some context, such as where you came across this notion. Was it in class? On your own? This will help the community to better aid you, especially if you plan to ask some more questions later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it really depends on the the context. A fibre space is sometimes referred to as a fibre bundle or a fibration.

Consider an object $(X,π,B),$ where $π:X→B$ is a continuous surjective mapping of a topological space $X$ onto a topological space $B$ (i.e., a *fibration*).

A fibre space can be regarded as the union of the fibres $π←[{b}],$ parametrized by the base space $B$ and glued by the topology of $X.$