# What is fiber space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, fiber-bundles

I'm reading a notes about algebraic topology.It uses a phrase 'fiber space' without any definition.I think maybe it's a generalization of fiber bundle.So I want to ask if there's anyone who knows what it means.

The following are some statements on the notes about 'fiber space'.

1. A fiber bundle over a topological space $B$ is a locally trivial fiber space,say, a $B$-space $(E,p)$ satisfying:for any $b \in B$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $b, s.t. (p^{-1}(V),p|_{p^{-1}(V)})$ is trivializable.(A $B$-space $(E,p)$ here means a pair $(E,p)$ where $E$ is a topological space and $p:E\longrightarrow B$ is a continuous map.)
2. Fiber space over any close interval [a,b] is trivializable.
3. If $(E,p)$ is a fiber space over topological space $B$,then $\{\ b\in B: p^{-1}(b)=\varnothing\}\ \ and \ \{\ b\in B: p^{-1}(b)\neq\varnothing\}=p(E)$ are both open in $B$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like they're using the phrase "fiber space" to mean fiber bundle.

Comment: @anon :But they said that a fiber bundle is a locally trivializable fiber space.

Comment: Probably this then: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration

Comment: Note: every fiber bundle over a paracompact topological space is a Hurewicz fibration, which is in turn a Serre (weak) fibration.

Comment: Do the notes give a definition of a trivializable fiber space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely a fibration. Have a look at [this](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=fiber+space&btnG=). It is certainly not necessarily a fiber bundle (which is defined as a locally trivial fiber space). Here are three references.

1. [WolframMathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiberSpace.html): A fiber space, depending on context, means either a fiber bundle or a fibration.
2. [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiberSpace.html): An object $(X,π,B)$, where $π:X→B$ is a continuous surjective mapping of a topological space X onto a topological space B (i.e., a *fibration*). Note that $X, B$ and $π$ are also called the *total space*, the *base space* and the *projection of the fibre space*, respectively.
   Note that this definition is flawed because a fibration is not the same as a continuous surjective mapping.
3. [Hurewicz, Witold. "On the concept of fiber space." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America 41.11 (1955): 956-961.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC534313/pdf/pnas00726-0160.pdf)
   Hurewicz has a very special definition of "fiber space", but proves that his fiber spaces are fibrations in the modern sense.

Also see [What is fiber space？Is it related to the fiber bundle？](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3565298)

Concerning your property 2 see [Pavešić, Petar. "A note on trivial fibrations." Glasnik matematički 46.2 (2011): 513-519.](https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/%7Epavesic/RESEARCH/A%20note%20on%20trivial%20fibrations.pdf)

However, it seems that your property 3 is not satisfied. Take for example the [closed topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) $S$. The inclusion of the oscillating part $O = \{(x,\sin(1/x)) \mid x \in (0,1] \}$ into the closed topologist's sine curve is a fibration, but the set of points of $S$ having a non-empty fiber is not open. See also [Surjectivity of Hurewicz fibrations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2893986).